# Why is there a massive delivery delay when sending from my Gmail account to an Earthlink account?

Tags: gmail, email

Lately I've been having a major problem with delivery delays when sending Gmail to a person that has an Earthlink account. Sending the email is fine but the mail does not arrive in the recipient's mailbox for many hours, and sometimes days. Oftentimes, I receive an email back from the mail daemon that says:

> Mail Delivery Subsystem to me show details 2:17 PM (5 minutes ago)
>   This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification
>
> THIS IS A WARNING MESSAGE ONLY.
>
> YOU DO NOT NEED TO RESEND YOUR MESSAGE.
>
> Delivery to the following recipient has been delayed:
>
> ```
> user@sfproperties.com
> ```
>
> Message will be retried for 2 more day(s)
>
> Technical details of temporary failure: The recipient server did not
>   accept our requests to connect. Learn more at
>   http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=7720
>   [mx00-dom.earthlink.net. (10): Connection timed out]
>   [mx01-dom.earthlink.net. (10): Connection timed out]

I'm not sure why this is happening, especially since I've been emailing this person for years without any delays – but now it happens almost every time I email her.

Answer (score 1):

Is it only this one e-mail address or all Earthlink accounts?

Some e-mail systems slow down if the inbox is full (or nearly full). So if your friend doesn't archive e-mails to other folders this could be an explanation.

If it happens with other accounts then it's a problem with the Earthlink servers.

---

While I understand that this is annoying, you have to remember that e-mail isn't guaranteed to be instantaneous. Mails can, and do, take days to reach their recipient under normal circumstances.